# Keep an Animated GIF Going After Form Submits

Tags: javascript, html

The following works for me in ie6,ie7,chrome but not ff3

```
document.getElementById("form-name").submit();
var image = document.getElementById("loader-img");
setTimeout(function() { image.src = image.src; },50);
```

What can I do for more consistency?

Comment: The animated GIF stops animating

Answer (score 1):

You should do the post asynchronously, if not the UI may hang. Take a look at the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) for more information.

Comment: Truth be told it's not a form submit, it is a document.location="url"; call

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to tell me. Please tell me why my answer is not solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set src to blank, then to image again. Second change may also need to be called later (settimeout).

Comment: Added: image.src = " ";  to the start of the function and saw no change

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the image node and replacing it? Something like:

```
var image = document.getElementById("loader-img");
image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
image.parentNode.appendChild(image);
```

(You might also need to do `image.cloneNode(true)` in between the remove and append calls.)

Obviously, your HTML needs to be structured so that this doesn't goof up the display.

But, what knut said applies (posting into a hidden IFRAME or using XHR will give you more control). And I'm not sure what you meant by "it's not a form submit, it is a document.location='url' call", so if you clarify the use case and workflow, I might be able to help more.