# How can I ensure my GIFs keep animating even after document.location="" has been run

Tags: javascript, html, gif, animated-gif

Take the following HTML:

```
<img src="/any-animated-gif.gf" alt="" />
<br /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="document.location='/anything-that-takes-a-few-seconds-to-load.html';return false;">Click Here</a>
```

When I click the link the icon stops.

Comment: How is this different from your question yesterday?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774515/keep-an-animated-gif-going-after-form-submits

Comment: Why are you emulating a link inside a link!? Just use <a href="/anything-that-takes-a-few-seconds-to-load.html">

Comment: Obviously there is more JS than what I gave, I stripped out the non-essentials...

Answer (score 2):

http://elliottback.com/wp/animated-gif-stops-javascript-click/

According to that link, reassigning the src of the image tag after you have made the redirect with javascript will keep the image animated. Not sure how this acts in firefox.

Comment: You will need to use a main DIV and then set the innerHTML value of that DIV with a AJAX request, or contain the image in an iframe. It says that at the bottom of the article if you notice. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the browser is going to a new page, all execution of the existing page stops *by design*. If you wish the current page to continue to function you need to use AJAX techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Documnet.Location instead of href?

You cannot change the browser's behavior. Once its loading a different page the current page will always stop.