# Show GIF-Animation after page request in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, animated-gif

I have a simple throbber, that is automatically shown when an ajax request lasts longer than 3 seconds. This throbber consists mainly of an animated GIF-Image.

Now, I want to use the same throbber also for regular links, meaning that when I click a link and it takes the server more than 3 seconds to respond, the throbber is shown.

Unfortunately, it seems that firefox is unable to play the animation, while it is "reloading" the webpage. The javascript is called and fades the throbber correctly in, but is it not spinning.

How can I make firefox play the GIF-Animation while it is loading?

Comment: You say it doesn't work in firefox, does that mean that it works in other browsers?

Comment: The application is only used in a few companies and all users are using firefox. So, I normally don't test in other browsers. 
After your comment I tested with Chrome and it works.

Comment: I think this relates to:
[this quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774515/keep-an-animated-gif-going-after-form-submits). 
So i guess there is no way to make firefox play the animation

Comment: Have you tried my script yet?

Comment: yes, and it didn't work (see my comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried my old code and found out that this issue does not exist anymore in Firefox 10.0.2

Answer (score 1):

This is the function:

```
// Throbber manager
function Throbber() { }
Throbber.prototype = {
    image : null,
    requests : 0,

    requestOpened : function(event) {
        if (this.requests == 0) {
            this.image.src = 'throbber.gif';
        }
        this.requests++;
    },

    requestLoaded : function(event) {
        this.requests--;
        if (this.requests == 0) {
            this.image.src = 'throbber_stopped.gif';
        }
    },

    clicked : function() {
        request_manager.abortAll();
    },

    // Called on window load
    attach : function() {
        this.image = document.getElementById('throbber');
        if (this.image && request_manager) {
            request_manager.addEventListener('open', [this, this.requestOpened]);
            request_manager.addEventListener('load', [this, this.requestLoaded]);
            request_manager.addEventListener('abort', [this, this.requestLoaded]);
            this.image.onclick = function() { Throbber.prototype.clicked.apply(throbber, arguments); };
        }
    }
}
var throbber = new Throbber();
window.addEventListener('load', function() { Throbber.prototype.attach.apply(throbber, arguments); }, false);

function SimpleDemo() { }
SimpleDemo.prototype = {
    // The AjaxRequest object
    request : null,

    // Setup and send the request
    run : function() {
        this.request = request_manager.createAjaxRequest();
        this.request.get = {
            one : 1,
            two : 2
        };
        this.request.addEventListener('load', [this, this.ran]);
        this.request.open('GET', 'xml.php');
        var req = requests[this.request.id];
        return setTimeout(function() { req.send(); }, 5000);
    },

    // Triggered when the response returns
    ran : function(event) {
        alert(event.request.xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

If you use jQuery:

```
$("#throbber").show();
/* Your AJAX calls */
$("#throbber").hide();
```

Check to see when the DOM is ready before calling all your Ajax stuff.

using Prototype:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  //your code
});
```

using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //your code
});
```

Or Refer this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/throbber

Comment: Hey, I am not sure, If that is really answering my question ... does `request_manager.addEventListener('open', [this, this.requestOpened]);
` mean that your throbber-version is called when I try to navigate away from the page (thus open a new webpage) or is it  just for ajax-requests?

Comment: seriously, please reread the question. I don't neet a generic throbber, i already have one. I am only having trouble when this throbber with a timeout is shown when I try to navigate away from a page, thus clicking an <a> tag that has an onlick-javascript that calls showThrobber, which creates a 3000ms timeout, that fades the throbber in.